# Dropdown on IE not working

Tags: css

This pure css dropdown menu works fine in Firefox, Chrome, Safari and Opera, but just shows the list in IE9.  It's assumed that it wouldn't work in older versions of IE.  It was my understanding IE9 solved the hover, etc. problems with dropdown menus.  How do I fix this?Thanks.

The pure CSS is:

```
body {
    background: ;
    font-family: Arial Black, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; line-height: 16px;
}

nav {
    margin: 0px auto; 
    text-align: center;
}

nav ul ul {
    display: none;
    width: 130px;
}

    nav ul li:hover > ul {
        display: block;
    }


nav ul {
    background: #; 
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    padding: 0 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;  
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-table;
}
    nav ul:after {
        content: ""; clear: both; display: block;
    }

    nav ul li {
        float: left;
    }
        nav ul li:hover {
            background: #377C37;

        }
            nav ul li:hover a {
                color: #fff;
            }

        nav ul li a {
            display: block; padding: 5px 40px;
            color: #757575; text-decoration: none;

        }


    nav ul ul {
        background: #5F6975; border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px; padding: 0px;
        position: absolute; top: 100%;
    }
        nav ul ul li {
            float: none; 
            border-top: 1px solid #;
            border-bottom: 0px solid #; position: relative;
            border-radius: 0px 10px 0px 0px; 
        }
            nav ul ul li a {
                padding: 3px 30px;
                color: #fff;
            }   
                nav ul ul li a:hover {
                    background: #3BA110;
                        border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px; 


                }

    nav ul ul ul {
        position: absolute; left: 100%; top:0;
            border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 10px; 

                }
```

The HTML is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml2/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>GRH Multi-Level</title>
<meta name="Author" content="George R. Hozendorf" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../down_menu_lawsart.css" />

</head>
<body>

<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="http://www.lawsart.com/Home.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.lawsart.com/About.html">About Me</a></li>

        <li><a>Portfolios &#9660</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a>Horses &#9658</a>

        <ul>
          <li><a href="http://www.lawsart.com/Horse1.html">Horses I</a></li>
          <li><a href="http://www.lawsart.com/Horse2.html">Horses II</a></li>
          <li><a href="http://www.lawsart.com/Horse3.html">Horses III</a></li>
          <li><a href="http://www.lawsart.com/Horse4.html">Horses IV</a></li>
          <li><a href="http://www.lawsart.com/Horse5.html">Horses V</a></li>
          <li><a href="http://www.lawsart.com/Horse6.html">Horses VI</a></li>
          <li><a href="http://www.lawsart.com/Horse7.html">Horses VII</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>

            <li><a>Dogs &#9658</a>

          <ul>
            <li><a href="http://www.lawsart.com/Dog1.html">Dogs I</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.lawsart.com/Dog2.html">Dogs II</a></li>
          </ul>
            </li>

            <li><a>People &#9658</a>

          <ul>
            <li><a href="http://www.lawsart.com/People1.html">People I</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.lawsart.com/People2.html">People II</a></li>
          </ul>
            </li>

            <li><a href="http://www.lawsart.com/Stills.html">Stills</a></li>

        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="http://www.lawsart.com/Order.html">Order</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.lawsart.com/Contact.html">Contact Me</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I just copied your code and tested it in IE9, and it is working. Can I suggest you may have compatibility mode on?

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and with the "Modernizr Library" add/include to your code everything works fine.  Even using IE8  http://modernizr.com/

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="modernizr.js"></script>
```

[image: Example]

[image: IE8]

Comment: Adding the modinizer just gave it a circle on the sub menu names.  Since it worked fine for Agustin I'm inclinded to think it's just a problem with the laptop I'm using to test the site in IE.

Comment: @user1887686 With Moderniz I downloaded a "Full Custom Package" where I activate all of the possible options.

Answer (score 0):

I was formatting your code and I realized that you missed the closing `</ul>` before the `</nav>`. Verify that

Comment: Thanks.  For some reason I can't find compatibility mode in the Tools menu to know if that's it or not.  The compatibility icon isn't visible.  Adding the closing </ul> didn't change anything either.  Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 0):

You have used html5 element which doesn't support ie old version. If you want to support html5 element in ie older version then just used following js in your html file withing head tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.createElement("nav");
</script>
```